# Non-negative, measurable, integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone tell me if this statement is true or false:

Let $f$ be a non-negative, measurable, integrable function on $[0,1].$ Then $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0}\int_0^a f(x) dx = 0$

and if false, provide a counterexample.

Comment: Hint: It's true for bounded measurable functions, and there is a sequence of such functions converging nicely to $f.$

Comment: Hint: dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It's true. Since $f \ge 0$ and $f\in L^1([0,1])$, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $E\subseteq [0,1]$ is measurable with $m(E) < \delta$, then $\int_E f(x)\, dx < \epsilon$. For all $a\in (0,1]$, $0 < a < \delta$ implies $m([0,a]) = a < \delta$, which implies $\int_0^a f(x)\, dx < \epsilon$. Hence $\lim\limits_{a\to 0} \int_0^a f(x)\, dx = 0$.